# Why is my employee getting this message when emailing thru PipelineDeals?

Tags: gmail-api

We have an employee using a 3rd party CRM (PipelineDeals) plugged into G-Suite.  After just around 1 or 2 emails sent thru PipelineDeals, she gets shut down and asked to wait 24 hours - gets this message.  And, now it doesn't even reset after 24 hours

[Rate Limit Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDGe1.png)

The other team members do not have this issue. And, we have contacted PipelineDeals and have stepped thru everything they said to do, with no success.

Comment: I doubt we can help. I'm sorry that PipelineDeals were not forthcoming with useful suggestions, but this really is in their court to solve.

Comment: PipelineDeals did all they could on their end - stated that it is a Google issue

Comment: Then have you contacted Google?

Comment: I followed this link and this is where I ended up.....https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support

Comment: I see. That is saying that they've "outsourced" programming-related API questions to this community. However, we are not technical support for Google and cannot help you when the service is not behaving as expected. You really will need to find a human to talk to at Google. I'm surprised PipelineDeals isn't fielding this for you, as your vendor. That's what you're paying them for, presumably! Sorry not to be of more help...

Comment: Hi ! Your issue seems to be exclusive to your case. Why don't you reach [G Suite technical support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and ask for 1:1 support to help you solve this behaviour?